# Configuring custom OpenID provider (Using .Net 6 and Identity server4) in Azure ADB2C giving error

Tags: identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, .net-6.0

I have created an OpenID provider using .Net 6 and Identity server4, now I am trying to use this as custom Identity provider in ADB2C, provided below configurations
[image: Configuration]
Getting below error everytime, not sure what and where it is going wrong:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

User side Identity Provider debugging is limited for User Flows. Problems usually boil down to incorrect openid config, secret or claim mappings. A known issue is caused by endpoint advertising EC keys since Azure AD B2C only supports RSA advertised keys.

In order to gain more user side debugging capabilities I suggest you switch to [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and follow the steps documented in [Troubleshooting with Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#troubleshooting-with-application-insights) and filter your logs using the correlation ID obtained during the error. You will need [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and the [Azure AD B2C extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureADB2CTools.aadb2c).

For additional debugging feel free to paste your app insights logs minus any PII (Personally identifiable information) information. In case you want to stick to User Flows paste here the debugging information (correlation id + timestamp) displayed in the error message.